# Dynamic Set Algebra on Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, set, pyspark, boolean-expression

Consider the following problem. Given:

1. A collection of sets
2. A boolean expression on them that is received dynamically

Return the resulting set.

Does Spark have any efficient algorithms or libraries to solve this general problem?

Here is a **toy** example to illustrate the problem conceptually:

```
val X  = Set("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
val Y  = Set("A2", "A4", "A5")

val collection = Set(X, Y)
val expression = "X and Y"
```

I am looking for a way of implementing a general `solve_expression` so that, in the example above:

```
output = solve_expression(expression, collection)
```

results in:

```
Set("A2", "A5")
```

---

I am working with sets with millions of items, and boolean expressions that come as strings. What's important is that each atom in the expression (e.g. "X", and "Y" above) are sets. The expressions and sets are *dynamic* (the operations can't be hard-coded, since we receive them as an input and we don't know what they are beforehand).

I am flexible with the representation of the problem. The actual sets can be of type `Set`, e.g. holding strings (e.g. "A1", "A2"), encoded as binary vectors, or anything else that makes this amenable to Spark.

Does Spark have any libraries to **parse** and **solve** general boolean expressions on sets?

Comment: What's the problem with using `X.union(Y)`? Or you want out-of heap solutions?

Comment: Why the downvote? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Thanks @ipoteka The expressions are dynamic (they can't be hard-coded in advance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright. Lets suppose you want to do this in Spark. Furthermore, since these are giant sets, let's suppose they aren't in memory yet, they are each in a file - with each line in a file denoting an entry in the set.

We will represent sets with `RDD`s - Spark's standard way of storing data.

Using this parser (adapted and fixed from [here](https://gist.github.com/sofoklis/3343973))

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.JavaTokenParsers
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

case class Query[T](setMap: Map[String, RDD[T]]) extends JavaTokenParsers {
  private lazy val expr: Parser[RDD[T]]
    = term ~ rep("union" ~ term) ^^ { case f1 ~ fs => (f1 /: fs)(_ union _._2) }
  private lazy val term: Parser[RDD[T]]
    = fact ~ rep("inter" ~ fact) ^^ { case f1 ~ fs => (f1 /: fs)(_ intersection _._2) }
  private lazy val fact: Parser[RDD[T]]
    = vari | ("(" ~ expr ~ ")" ^^ { case "(" ~ exp ~ ")" => exp })
  private lazy val vari: Parser[RDD[T]]
    = setMap.keysIterator.map(Parser(_)).reduceLeft(_ | _) ^^ setMap

  def apply(expression: String) = this.parseAll(expr, expression).get.distinct
}
```

Observe the following `spark-shell` interaction after having pasted the above into the shell (I've omitted some of the replies for brevity):

```
> val x = sc.textFile("X.txt").cache \\ contains "1\n2\n3\n4\n5"
> val y = sc.textFile("Y.txt").cache \\ contains "3\n4\n5\n6\n7"
> val z = sc.textFile("Z.txt").cache \\ contains "3\n9\n\10"
> val sets = Map("x" -> x, "y" -> y, "z" -> z)
> val query = Query[Int](sets)
```

Now, I can call query with different expressions. Notice that here I'm using `collect` to trigger evaluation (so we see what is inside the set), but if the sets are really big, you would normally just keep the `RDD` as is (and save it to disk).

```
> query("a union b").collect
res: Array[Int] = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7")
> query("a inter b").collect
res: Array[Int] = Array("3", "4", "5")
> query("a inter b union ((a inter b) union a)").collect
res: Array[Int] = Array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
> query("c union a inter b").collect
res: Array[Int] = Array("3", "4", "5", "9", "10")
> query("(c union a) inter b").collect
res: Array[Int] = Array("3", "4", "5")
```

Although I didn't bother to implement it, set difference should be a one-line addition (very similar to `union` and `inter`). I think set complements are a bad idea... they don't always make sense (what is the complement of the empty set, how do you represent it?).

Comment: Although I agree that one should use Parser Combinator, this looks strange. Does it generate trillions of rdds, right? But on some level you should switch to scala collection set.

Comment: @ipoteka I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "trillions of rdds" - it will make as many RDDs as you have operands in your expression, so on the order of only a handful. Yes, of course OP should use scala collections if his sets are small enough - but the question explicitly asks about Spark...